# Is there anyway to fast the scrolling of viewpager

Tags: android

I want `ViewPager` scrolling fast. Once we scroll, it should take me to `ViewPager's` last item.

I was using `ViewPagerCustomDuration`. But it didn't work

```
ViewPagerCustomDuration1 vp = view.findViewById(R.id.overlap_pager);
vp.setScrollDurationFactor(20);
```

Comment: Thanks, Dinesh...Do you have any solution regarding this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understand your question: do you want the viewpager to scroll everytime to the last item, even if you just start the scroll gesture on an item not adjacent to the last item?

Comment: @AntCopp When we scroll recyclerview horizontally.Exactly I want viewpager to be scroll .

Comment: But why use a viewpager if you're going to always go to the last item? It's like having a TWO PAGE BOOK, no matter what first page you chose.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jka2emp06xubxvj/WhatsApp%20Video%202019-06-12%20at%207.25.53%20AM.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Have a look, This is already implemented in iOS but now I want in android. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the continuous scrolling effect, then you may try `HorizontalScrollView` or `RecyclerView` (with horizontal `LinearLayoutManager`) instead of `ViewPager`.

Comment: not only scrolling effect but two more thigs are working on this viewpager
1. When we click on a previous ad next viewpager item it should come to the center respectively
2.A dialog box is opening on center  viewpager item